# Trivial singly-linked list inquiry

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The addToHead function of the linked list class is not working properly. The function seems to be replacing the head. Help. Please.

```
template <class T>
class LinkedNode {
  public:
    LinkedNode(T);
    T element;
    LinkedNode<T> *next;
};

template <class T>
LinkedNode<T>::LinkedNode(T e){
    element = e;
    next = 0;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////
template <class E>
class LinkedList {
  public:
    LinkedList();
    void addToHead(E);
    LinkedNode<E> *head, *tail, *temp;
};

template <class E>
LinkedList<E>::LinkedList() {
    head = tail = NULL;
}

template <class E>
void LinkedList<E>::addToHead(E e) {
    LinkedNode<E> a(e);
    if (head == NULL)
        head = tail = &a;
    else {
        a.next = head;
        head = &a;
    }
}

int main(){
    LinkedList<int> list;
    list.addToHead(55);
    list.addToHead(22);
    cout << list.head->element << " trivial "<< list.head->next->element << endl;
}
```

Comment: sci: Use a markdown code block (instead of HTML formatting) and it'll escape the < and > automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `addToHead()`, you are assigning the *address of a local variable* to the `head` element of your list. After this function returns, the local variable is destroyed and must not be accessed.

One way to fix this is to use dynamic allocation to make a new `LinkedNode<E>`:

```
template <class E>
void LinkedList<E>::addToHead(E e) {
    LinkedNode<E> *a = new LinkedNode<E>(e);
    if (head == NULL)
        head = tail = a;
    else {
        a->next = head;
        head = a;
    }
}
```

After allocating memory for this node, your `LinkedList` class should also be responsible for freeing the node (with `delete`) at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedNode a(e);` is only in the scope of addToHead. The pointer to it (`&a`) gets invalidated as soon as the function returns.